# Checking for a substring in a Firebase Firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I already worked through the documentation of Googles FireBase security rules, but I am struggling to get a verification done, where the eMail-address of the FireBase Authtoken is checked if it is part of a domain (like "*@test.de") before reading the FireStore-database is allowed.

I tried:

```
auth.token.email.matches(/.*@test.de$/)
```

I copied it from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database , but it doesn't seem to work for FireStore.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full rule that doesn't work the way you expect, as well as the code on the client that it should allow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple if you know the correct syntax.

You can do it like this:

```
  allow read: if request.auth.token.email.matches('.*@test[.]de');
```